# In React, how would i convert certain aspects of a stateful component to work within a function component?

Tags: reactjs

My code is in React & is quite extensive, so i have provided a codesandbox link:  [My transactions section of my "under construction" app:](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-sea-96048)    https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-sea-96048.  A Chegg expert had given me the code that renders what you'll see above my transaction cards (his ModalEdit, for now, was placed inside of the TransactionsLayout component--this is just so you can visualize, somewhat, of what i'm looking for).
i like the way that the edit does what my question is asking.  however, i do not know how to make it work within the framework of my app, because my TransactionCard.jsx file is a function component without state.  and, the expert's code is with state.

i have tried putting his code as a separate component & calling to it with the button onClick (line#69 on the TransactionsCard.jsx file).  however, this doesn't work because i can't figure out 'how' to convert his code to work within the framework of the transactions' files.

Comment: You want to use react modal? The thing you are importing on line 12?

Comment: I would like to use react modal, but am open to trying whatever you might suggest